# Having Difficulties with Mods On Pc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I downloaded mods a few minutes ago (aka Advanced Capes, Not Enough Items, Rei's Mini Map, and Simply Sit all for 1.7.10) but all that pops up when I try to launch the game, a whole bunch coding comes up. Should I delete everything? I'd rather not, but I will if I have to.

Comment: Try reading [this FAQ](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/how-do-i-ask-minecraft-questions/10103#10103) about how to ask a good Minecraft Crash question, then add some extra information so we can help you further.

Comment: You probably need Minecraft Forge to make the mods work - check http://files.minecraftforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Without any additional information, there is literally nothing we can tell you to fix your issue outside of "Start over".

Easiest way to fix this issue is to delete everything, then start from Vanilla Minecraft. Install each mod **one at a time**, then launch Minecraft and verify that it's still working.

It might even be best to backup your .Minecraft folder after each successful mod install. This way if you do run into a mod that causes any issues, you can revert to the last known-good configuration.